# When my conditional is false in when it turns true why wont the loop stop

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, while-loop, statements

Here is my code
in python 3.4 it just keeps running the loop until the system exit when the player dies this is part of an rpg game i have been making for fun

Not entire code please note if you would like to see entire code please ask only combat function shown

```
def combat(h, a, d, x):
    global attack
    global health
    global defence
    global xp
    death = False
    while death == False:
        eab = random.randint(1, 10)
        yab = random.randint(1, 10)
        cattack = 0
        cdefence = 0
        cattack = attack
        cdefence = defence
        cattack = cattack + yab
        a = a + eab
        d = d - cattack
        print("you strike for " + str(cattack) + " damage")
        cattack = cattack - d
        if cattack > 0:
            h = h - cattack
        if d > 0:
            print("the enemy has " + str(d) + "defence left")
        if h > 0:
            print("the enemy has " + str(h) + "Health left")
        else :
            print("the enemy dies")
            death == True
            xp = xp + x
        print("they strike back for " + str(a))
        cdefence = cdefence - a
        a = a - cdefence
        if a > 0:
            health = health - a
        if cdefence > 0:
            print("you have " + str(cdefence) + " defence left!")
        if health > 0:
            print("you have " + str(health) + " health left")
        else :
            sys.exit("YOU DIED A HORRIBLE DEATH")
```

Comment: `death == True`. You're not assigning `True` to `death`, you're just comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line: `death == True`

This compares the variable 'death' with the `True` function, which will never work. What you need to do instead is replace that with `death = True`.

This should fix your code.